# DRF - Filter queryset in PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've the following models:

```
class ModelX(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'ABC'),
        (1, 'DEF'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users)


class Users(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.Charfield()
```

and the serializer for ModelX is :

```
class ModelXSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone_number = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source='user', queryset=Users.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number))

    class Meta:
        model = ModelX
        fields = ('phone_number',)
```

In the request for creating the `ModelX` record, I get `phone_number` instead of the user_id. Now, I've to fire a filter query in order get the `user` instance. How do I do that, ie `Users.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)`

Also, when creating a record, the `status` field will always be `0`. The client wont post the `status` parameter in the body. Its the internal logic. Is there a way in `serializers` that can set the `status` field to `0` automatically. **Please dont recommend to set this field as default=0 in models**. There's some logic behind this. This is just a shorter version of the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it in `validate` function:

```
class ModelXSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super(ModelXSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
        attrs['status'] = 0
        return attrs
```

Comment: It works good. Just curious to know, is it the standard way of doing it or can it also be done by providing a value to a serializer field? Such as `status = serializers.StringField(value=0)`. Kindly guide. Thanks.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: Following the [Core arguments](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) article, Using **value** arg is maybe not the standard way.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: In this case, you are **deserializing data** and you must need the **validation** step. Using `validate` function is [Object-level validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)

Comment: Sounds Good. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try such version of your serializer, with custom `create` method:

```
class ModelXSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(source='user.phone_number')

    class Meta:
        model = ModelX
        fields = ('phone_number',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_number = validated_data['phone_number']
        user = Users.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
        instance = ModelX.objects.create(status=0, user=user)
        return instance
```

details about the [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument.

Comment: What is "source" used for?      for me  validated_data = {.........,'user': {'phone_number':#value},.....}